# Query Contains for Entity Relationship 1:n

Tags: filter, widget, typo3, extbase, fluid

I want to check if the word $filterwords occurs in one of the objects and filter them in my widget Filter.

The structure is as follows:
Class Blog have n Features. And a Feature has a Name.

For Example:

```
   Blog1
    -Feature1
     --Name "Fast"
    -Feature2
     --Name "Beautiful"
   Blog2
    -Feature1
     --Name "Fast"
   Blog3
    -Feature2
     --Name "Beautiful"
```

Now I want all blogs that have the property "Fast".

In the List.html I would actually like to call my filter like this:

```
<example:widget.myfilter objects="{blogs}" as="filteredblogs" property="features.name">
```

But this is not possible, because features are n objects.
"Unsupported or non-existing property name "name" used in relation matching."

Therefore it only works like this:

```
<example:widget.myfilter objects="{blogs}" as="filteredblogs" property="features">
```

So in my widget filter controller I get the property like this:

```
    /**
     * @var QueryResultInterface
     */
    protected $objects;
    public function initializeAction()
    {
        $this->objects = $this->widgetConfiguration['objects'];
        $this->property = $this->widgetConfiguration['property'];
        $this->as = $this->widgetConfiguration['as'];
    }

    /**
     * @param string $filterword
     */
    public function indexAction(string $filterword = ""): void
    {
        $query = $this->objects->getQuery();
        $query->matching($query->contains($this->property, $filterword));
...
```

The problem now is that the "Contains" query does not work because he would have to check for the property "Feature"->"Name". But it does not pass "Feature.name" as property but only "features". Somehow you have to tell the "Contains" that it should check for "Name".

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have obviously found the problem.

The following now works in List.html:

```
<example:widget.myfilter objects="{blogs}" as="filteredblogs" property="features.uid">
```

In the Controller:

```
$features = $this->featureRepository->getFeaturesByName($filterfeature);
        $query = $this->objects->getQuery();
        if(count($features) > 0) {
            $query->matching($query->in($this->property, $features));
        }
```

But the real problem is obviously that I have connected 2 filters in a row.

```
<example:widget.myfilter objects="{blogs}" as="filteredblogs" property="features.uid">
    <example:widget.anotherfilter objects="{filteredblogs}" as="filteredmoreblogs" property="test.name">
```

The problem is that it only uses the 2nd filter. If I remove the 2nd filter the first one works.